# Project reactor: collectList() doesn't work for Flux.create()

Tags: java, reactor

Below example prints integers from 1 to 10 and a list of (7, 8, 9, 10)

```
public void streamCollect() {

    ConnectableFlux<Integer> connect = Flux.range(1, 10)
            .publish();

    connect.subscribe(v -> System.out.println("1: " + v));

    connect
            .filter(number -> number > 6)
            .collectList()
            .subscribe(v -> System.out.println("4: " + v));

    connect.connect();
}
```

Result:

1: 1

1: 2

1: 3

1: 4

1: 5

1: 6

1: 7

1: 8

1: 9

1: 10

4: [7, 8, 9, 10]

Next example should produce the same result but instead prints out only numbers from 1 to 10 but no list. Why?

```
public void streamCollect() {

    ConnectableFlux<Integer> connect = Flux.<Integer>create(emitter -> {

        Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
                .forEach(t -> emitter.next(t));
    }).publish();

    connect.subscribe(v -> System.out.println("1: " + v));

    connect
            .filter(number -> number > 6)
            .collectList()
            .subscribe(v -> System.out.println("4: " + v));

    connect.connect();
}
```

Result:

1: 1

1: 2

1: 3

1: 4

1: 5

1: 6

1: 7

1: 8

1: 9

1: 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The collectList waits for the onComplete signal, which you never produce in your create lambda

Comment: Once again works like a charm. I understand why complete() has to be called but how to gain this knowledge with other means than stackoverflow. I mean is there some general rule? Or the mistake was that complete() should be called always when operating on FluxSink after all items were emitted, period.