# Project reactor: block() after collectList() doesn't work for Flux.create()

Tags: java, spring, reactor

When I call block() on the Mono<> instance returned by collectList() in the sample below, my code hangs despite having called complete() on the emitter.

I recognize that calling block() isn't advised under most circumstances.  I'm writing test code, and my use of it seemed reasonable -- aside from the fact that it doesn't work.

The code below is a slightly modified version of [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49732852/project-reactor-collectlist-doesnt-work-for-flux-create).

```
    ConnectableFlux<Integer> connect = Flux.<Integer>create(emitter -> {
        Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
          .forEach(t -> emitter.next(t));
        emitter.complete();
    }).publish(); // EDIT <- use .replay() 

    connect.subscribe(v -> System.out.println("1: " + v));

    Mono<List<Integer>> mono = connect
            .filter(number -> number > 6)
            .collectList();

    mono.subscribe(v -> System.out.println("4: " + v));

    connect.connect();
    List<Integer> results = mono.block(); //hangs here
```

EDIT:  Using replay() instead of publish() as shown in the comment above allows the block() to resolve as I had initially expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `block()`, you subscribe to your `Mono` and `ConnectableFlux`, but you don't connect to your flux source. Previous `connect.connect()` doesn't affect this subscription.

Your last row could be like this:

```
List<Integer> results = connect
        .autoConnect()
        .filter(number -> number > 6)
        .collectList()
        .block();
```

Comment: Thank you, this works.  After some more research, I realized that replacing `publish()` with `replay()` in my example also works for what I want.  With `replay()`, subsequent subscriptions do not re-trigger the source, but they do receive a replay of what has already been emitted.